# Dynamically restructure HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two HTML tables that I need to merge together, and then output the result as a separate table. 
[image: BeforeTables]

The function `objectify()` finds each of the pre-merge tables and puts their data into objects in the following format: [image: object structure]

It is from this point onwards things get tricky. My `standardise()` function loops through each object, placing the header and date values into arrays, and then calling `removeDuplicates()` to remove the duplicates (self-explanatory).

However, when it comes to merging each of the objects together and outputting the data into a table, I cannot think of how to do it. So far, I can only figure how to output the table headers, like so:
[image: aftertab]

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrvXgm) is a link to my codepen. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: would it be possible to give an example of the resulting table?

Comment: Why don't you just compare the data as string in the first common TD and than you fill the rest? Using **each** to loop the first common TD and **:contains** to find the td with the same data in the other table, than with **closest('tr')** you should be able to do the trick.

Comment: @Vixed would it be possible for you to write a small example? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sorry, not right now @MikeResoli, but can you please tell me if are using a query to for generating tables? if yes, I think is better to use union in mysql or sql  select instead all this javascript.

Comment: @MikeResoli I made a fidde to let you understand what is missing https://jsfiddle.net/6q9dqozp/ I'll try to help you this evening. Sorry again.

Comment: @Vixed thanks for your help, you've pushed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed a bit of your code an now seems to work.
http://jsfiddle.net/dt1dmmk2/

```
function removeDuplicates(array) {
  var cleanValues = [];
  $.each(array, function(i, el) {
    if ($.inArray(el, cleanValues) === -1) cleanValues.push(el);
  });
  return cleanValues;
}
var titles=[];
var totRow=0
  $('.before table').each(function() {
    var rowNumber=$('tr',this).length-1;
    if (totRow<rowNumber)
      totRow=rowNumber;

    var firstCol;
    var secondCol;
    $('tr',this).each(function(index) {
      if (index == 0) {
        firstCol=$('td:first',this).text();
        secondCol=$('td:last',this).text();
        titles.push(firstCol,secondCol)
      } else {
        $('td:first',this).attr('data-col',firstCol);
        $('td:last',this).attr('data-col',secondCol);
      }
    });
  })
  titles=removeDuplicates(titles);
  $('.after table').append('<tr>');
  for (i in titles) {
    $('.after table tr:last').append('<th>' + titles[i] + '</th>');
  }
    for (var b=0;b<totRow;b++) {
      $('.after table').append('<tr />')
      for (i in titles) {
            var textToFill=$('.before td[data-col="'+titles[i]+'"]:first').text();
            $('.after table tr:last').append('<td>'+textToFill+ '</td>');
            $('.before td[data-col="'+titles[i]+'"]:first').removeAttr('data-col')
      }
    }
    $('td[data-col]').removeAttr('data-col'); // just to clean
```

Of course the TR has be ordered in the **.before table** and in this way you'll not need to rearrange the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q9dqozp) will help you to understand what are you missing ;)

```
/* please check this loop. Here you have to put your cleanYCol as well */
  for (i in cleanXCol) {
    $(resultsTableBody).append("<tr />")
    $('tr:last',resultsTableBody).append("<td>" + cleanXCol[i] + "</td>");
    // $('tr:last',resultsTableBody).append("<td>" + cleanYCol[i] + "</td>");
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6q9dqozp

Comment: Thanks for that, I am now printing the data from the first table in the correct column successfully. However, as number of pre-merge table rows for each table is 7, the length of the `cleanYCol` array will be 14. As I have gathered all the dates from the tables and removed the duplicates (resulting in `cleanXCol`), it means there are only 7. How would I write a statement to print the other half of `cleanYCol`?